# Cannot import db from app in flask when imported in subdirectory of app

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Directory structure:

```
app/__init__.py
        models/__init__.py
               user.py
```

I declare db in hte app init file. I then want to use the db instance in my user model to declare my user model. `db` isn't found when doing `from app import db`, yet other variables in that file like the `api` instance can be.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that this was a circular import error. `__init__` was referencing the `api` namespace, which had a model import, which had a database import from the `app`. Shifting around the import statements to initialise `app` first, then the `db` and only then importing the `api` namespace fixed it.

Very simple in the end and I should have read the docs properly. The missing variables were all those that were unassigned at the point of the import circularity.